# Vanilla Javascript Error IE only

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, onload, deferred

I won't bother you with too much "blahblahblah" as most of you will know the following script all too well. A lot of questions popped up around this topic after Google let this beast out to play in the wild.

```
var elements = [
    "script1.js",
    "script2.js"
];

var downloadJSAtOnload = function(elements) {

    if (toString.call(elements) !== "[object Array]") {
        return false
    }

    var i, element;
    for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        element = document.createElement("script");
        element.src = elements[i];
        document.body.appendChild(element)
    }

    return true
};

if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener("load", function() {
            downloadJSAtOnload(elements)
        }

        , false)
} else {
    if (window.attachEvent) {
        window.attachEvent("onload", function() {
            downloadJSAtOnload(elements)
        })
    } else {
        window.onload = function() {
            downloadJSAtOnload(elements)
        }
    }
};
```

This script is doing what it has to do in all browsers but IE10 and 11 from what I can see. I tested with browserstack and real machines with the same result.

May be it is due to minification of the script so I will also give you the minified version of the above script, as we are using it in our live environment:

```
var elements=["script1.js","script2.js"],downloadJSAtOnload=function(n){if("[object Array]"!==toString.call(n))return!1;var t,e;for(t=0;t<n.length;t++)e=document.createElement("script"),e.src=n[t],document.body.appendChild(e);return!0};window.addEventListener?window.addEventListener("load",function(){downloadJSAtOnload(elements)},!1):window.attachEvent?window.attachEvent("onload",function(){downloadJSAtOnload(elements)}):window.onload=function(){downloadJSAtOnload(elements)};
```

Anything I was doing wrong here? As it is indeed doing its thing in FF, Chrome, Safari and Opera I was expecting IE (you can call me a fool, now) to behave... at least once.

Comment: Unclosed statements will definitly break the code when minified. You could try this, if i didnt miss any line: http://pastebin.com/EMCFYCJW

Comment: Alright. Thank you.

But how come the script is working in all browsers then but refuses to work in IE? I don't get this.

Comment: I think those are more forgiving then IE. I commented based on something "i assumed" was the problem, havent looked into the browser specific technical details on how they parse scripts etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems the Error is on `"[object Array]"!==toString.call(n)`.

The IE can't referer to the function `toString()` directly when using `.call( something )`. You can use following code to fix your Problem:

*not minifed*

```
if( Object.prototype.toString.call(elements) !== "[object Array]") {
    return false;
}
```

*minified*

```
if("[object Array]"!==Object.prototype.toString.call(n)) return !1;
```

See more Informations about the toString()-Function here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString under "Using toString() to detect object class".

Comment: Thanks so much for helping me out!
This solved the issue. =)

You are a hero.